# jQuery mobile strange form behaviour

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile

I'm developing a mobile application using phonegap and trying to integrate a form using jquery to post data to an sql database but the form seems to acting in a strange way. 
If I set the application to navigate directly to the form page upon startup of the application it works fine but if I try to navigate to the form page from an different initial page the form will refuse to work.
The problem seems to be with declaring the jquery mobile script on the first initial page.

If anybody has any idea what's going on that would be great because I just can't figure it out!

HTML for page with link

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>     
<title>jQuery form post</title> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel" >
<div data-role="header" >
    <h1>New Submission</h1>
</div>      

<div data-role="content">

<a href="comment_2.html" data-role = "button">New Submission</a>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

HTML for page with form

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>     
<title>jQuery form post</title>   
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="js/post.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel" >
<div data-role="header" >
    <h1>New Submission</h1>
</div>      

<div data-role="content">

<div id="landmark-1" data-landmark-id="1">
<form id="comment">
    <label for="email">
        <b>Email</b>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
    </label>

    <label for="comment">
        <b>Comment</b>
        <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery mobile is not even including your post.js when it is not the first page. This is how it works, everything on the first page is loaded and after that it will inject the data-role="page" via AJAX. This behavior is documented [here](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/faq/scripts-and-styles-not-loading.html).

To fix it, you have two options:

1. Use one of the [page change events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/) to execute the code.
2. Move your code inside the data-role="page" div.

Comment: Thank you!!
Got it working by moving the script into the data-role="page" div.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in comment.html page head section:

```
<script src="js/post.js"></script>
```

Should work?! Or am i missing something?

Comment: Just tried and updated it in the comment.html page but still not working!